# How to simulate onFailureListener & resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK In App Updates?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, in-app-update

How can I test this *onFailureListener & resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK*?

When I open the app, I create a force Update State depending on my versionName of both apps shared on Google Play Internal Sharing.

At first, it will show me a custom dialog. On Negative Btn -> The app close

On Positive Btn -> The checkForUpdate() fun will start.

I use AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE. So it will show me only the Google Play dialog for UPDATE.

I just made a build for inAppUpdates and I'm trying to handle onFailureListener.
Without putting just a printstacktrace, I want to Open Google Play, and let user to install the app from there.

```
fun checkForAppUpdate() {
        val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this)
        val appUpdatedListener: InstallStateUpdatedListener by lazy {
            object : InstallStateUpdatedListener {
                override fun onStateUpdate(installState: InstallState) {
                    if(installState.installStatus() == InstallStatus.INSTALLED) {
                        appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(this)
                    }
                    else {Log.d("inAPPtag","InstallStateUpdatedListener: state: %s" + installState.installStatus())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
        val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo
        // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE || appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {

                appUpdateManager.registerListener(appUpdatedListener)
                // Request the update.
                try {
                    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                        appUpdateInfo,
                        AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                        this,
                         APP_UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE
                    )
                } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnFailureListener {
            it.printStackTrace()
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(Constants.STORE_URL))
            if (intent.resolveActivity(this.packageManager) != null) {
                splashTrace.putAttribute("SPLASH", "appUpdate")
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, if resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK. The same thing, to let the user install the app from Google Play.

```
if (requestCode == APP_UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE) {
           if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
               val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(Constants.STORE_URL))
               if (intent.resolveActivity(this.packageManager) != null) {
                   splashTrace.putAttribute("SPLASH", "appUpdate")
                   startActivity(intent)                    
                   finish()
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two places where your trying to catch an error in your app.

The first one is a SendIntentException, as per documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentSender.SendIntentException) it says that:

> Exception thrown when trying to send through a PendingIntent that has been canceled or is otherwise no longer able to execute the request.

I guess this would happen if you trigger the `startUpdateFlowForResult` from another part of your code then the first one will get canceled and trigger this exception.

The second error is on the `appUpdateInfoTask.addOnFailureListener {`. I believe this one will get triggered if the phone doesn't have the Google Play Store or if the device has no internet connection.

Regarding your second question, you can [check here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#RESULT_CANCELED). For an onActivityResult you have three options:

1. RESULT_OK: the update was a success
2. RESULT_CANCELED: user hit the back button
3. RESULT_FIRST_USER: a user defined flow